# System Testing a Mongoose Server

Tags: c++14, mongoose-web-server

I'm curious as to the best/correct way to setup System level black-box tests for a Mongoose C++ based Web Application project I've been working on. This needs to run in an automatic way within a jenkins script.

The idea is to run something like:

```
1. Start the server
2. Submit HTTP Get requests with predefined query parameters
3. Check that the result is as expected.
4. Run (2), (3) with different combinations
5. Close the server
```

One possible way to do this is to whip up a python script which runs the executable generate by `make`, runs the tests and then kills the spawned process.

Is there a better/more structured way of doing this(and accompanying tools/libraries) either using Python or C++?

Comment: You can check Mongoose library testing code, https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/tree/master/test

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @valenok. It would be nice to get some minimal sample code for one of the examples here https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/tree/master/examples?